# Magento Customer Reports only showing 5 results per day

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, ce-1.8.1.0, reports

The reporting functions are a mess. I love the flexibility of Magento but some things are really bad.

I want to create a ranking list of our best customers. However the Magento Customer Report only shows a maximum of 5 orders per day. This seems to be a rule set by the system but I can't find where to change it. Statistics are refreshed.

I'm running Magento 1.8.1.0 without any order report extensions installed.

Does anyone know why the report is limited to 5 entries and how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

The number of results is limited directly on the report block class code. You can create a module or make an override to change this value. I would create a module that would add a field to the configuration panel (using system.xml) to be free to change this value at any time.

The limit is defined in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid`.

File: app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Grid.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    ... 
    protected $_subReportSize = 5;
    ...
}
```

**NOTE: Do not change the code directly into the core!**